# Using only one reducer throw me errors with ngrx

Tags: angular, dictionary, redux, store, ngrx

I am working on Angular with a store, and I cannot build my project because of some redux' errors.

Actually, the only way to make my store working, is with this configuration

app.module.ts - imports

```
StoreModule.forRoot({applicationState: AppReducer}),
```

app.reducer.ts

```
export function AppReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): AppState {
switch (action.type) {
    case types....:
      return {...state, ...};
...
```

In my components

```
this.store.select(s => s.applicationState.myValue).subscribe()...
```

It doesn't build correctly, but when I serve twice, I can at least test my project. Since I dont have any substate (my Appstate is full of number, arrays, etc but no substate), and only one reducer, I dont get how I should declare my ActionMapReducer in my app.module.ts, to be able to subscribe to my values like that:

```
this.store.select('myValue').subscribe(..)
```

I tried many things, looked into many samples, but I cannot figure out how to fix that, and my project cannot build because of that :(.

Comment: Do you have a default in your switch in your reducer ?

Comment: Yes I do. Everything else works "fine", I just cannot get my store values properly.

Comment: Could you send error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot use ngrx's store without ReducerMap, even if you have only one reducer. :(

This does the job

index.ts

```
export interface State {
    state: AppState; // contains my store, real 'state'
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = { // State isnt my 'real' state !
  state: AppReducer
};

export const getValueState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('state')
export const getValue = createSelector(getValueState, (state: AppState) => state.value);
```

app.moduls.ts - imports

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
```

component.ts

```
this.store.select(getValue).subscribe(...);
```

I still cannot figure out why I couldn't use a selector like select('myValue') ... but it's fine now.